# Can't delete npm proxy

Tags: proxy, npm

In work I have a proxy and set this in npm

```
 npm config set proxy http://theproxy:8080
 npm config set https-proxy https://theproxy:8080
```

Out of work I don't have the proxy and need to remove it in npm.

I've tried

```
 npm config rm proxy
 npm config rm https-proxy
```

and

```
 npm config delete proxy
 npm config delete https-proxy
```

but when I use

```
 npm config get proxy
 npm config get https-proxy
```

the proxy is still there

How do I remove the proxy in npm

Answer (score 3):

Below things worked for me, make sure environment variable HTTP_PROXY is unset before removing config entries

## Unsetting  HTTP_PROXY= is very important

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config rm http-proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

It works very well for me ..

```
saidas-mbp:trunk saidababuchanda$ npm config set proxy https://www.google.com
saidas-mbp:trunk saidababuchanda$ npm config get proxy 
https://www.google.com
saidas-mbp:trunk saidababuchanda$ npm config delete proxy 
saidas-mbp:trunk saidababuchanda$ 
saidas-mbp:trunk saidababuchanda$ npm config get proxy 
null
saidas-mbp:trunk saidababuchanda$ npm -v
1.4.14
saidas-mbp:trunk saidababuchanda$
```

Please look at your npm version

Comment: If I do `npm config ls -l `    I get a list of all settings which includes `proxy = "proxy.theproxy.co.uk:8080" `. If I do `npm config set proxy https://www.google.com ` and then `npm config ls -l ` google.com is set as the proxy but I still have  `; proxy = "proxy.theproxy.co.uk:8080" (overridden) `. I have version 1.4.14. Is it a good idea to delete the npm install, will that help in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

npm config delete proxy
npm config delete proxy -g
npm config delete https-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy -g

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was trying to delete the proxy while I was in specific folder project that contains .npmrc file.
Inside the file there was proxy definition for this specific folder.
So I removed the proxy definition inside.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt , it is set somewhere in your npmrc files , can you check below files?to see if this value is set somewhere.

npmrc Files

The four relevant files are:
per-project config file (/path/to/my/project/.npmrc)
per-user config file (~/.npmrc)
global config file ($PREFIX/npmrc)
npm builtin config file (/path/to/npm/npmrc)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
npm config rm http-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you need to remove it globally. Try:

```
npm config rm proxy -g
npm config rm https-proxy -g
```

Answer (score 0):

## Three steps solution.

What worked for me is setting the `proxy` to an empty string / url, then I used `npm config delete` to remove the `https-proxy` setting.

So i ran the following commands:

```
npm config set proxy
npm config delete https-proxy -g
```

Additionally you can run `npm config list` to verify that the values indeed have been removed.

Now one last thing, you need to run the following command:

`npm config edit`

A file will open on your default text editor, in that file remove any proxy configurations added by you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions in this thread but it didn't work. The issue was that proxy settings were commented in my "C:\Users\YOURNAME.npmrc" file. Uncommenting it worked for me.

**proxy=null**

**https-proxy=null**

Answer (score 0):

First, type this to see the current config:

```
npm config get
```

If you see any config about a proxy, you can delete that with the name of its key.
In my case I had a line: `registry = "http://172.16.10.54:4777"`
I deleted it with the command:

```
npm config delete registry
```

And that worked fine!